# Date filter not same behave Production and Development environment in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

```
DateTime minExpDate = aDetail.ExpiryDate.Date;
DateTime maxExpDate = aDetail.ExpiryDate.Date.AddDays(1);

var sp = GenService.GetAll<StockPosition>()
           .FirstOrDefault(r => r.WarehouseId == fromWarehouseId &&
           r.ProductId == aDetail.ProductId &&
           r.ExpiryDate >= minExpDate &&
           r.ExpiryDate < maxExpDate
           );

if (sp == null)
  {
   response.Message = "Not enough product available in stock";
   return response;
  }
```

When I execute this code from Development Environment It's work fine. I got an object in sp.
But when I deploy it in IIS. and run it from production environment sp get Null.
why behave like this when run from production.
I am running it development and production on the same sql server

Comment: y do u think it a datetime problem? if it is a different db (as it should be), y wouldn't have the same data you have on dev on prod

Comment: @DamilolaAdegunwa yes it is datetime problem. I have test it. and I already use diff sql server with same data. it show same result when goes production.

Comment: Check that develop and production server are in same timezone

Comment: @Ygalbel I use same pc for production and development.

Comment: The only thing I can think about is the user you are connecting to your DB. Where is your connection string? Is it possible that is override in IIS or Web.config?

Comment: @Ygalbel I have checked same connection string use for dev and pro.

Comment: same connection string.. and you don't happen to use SqLite with similar SqLite database files in \Debug and \Release ? (I've had that once.. got me searching for hours hehe)

Comment: Try to use [asp.net core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to log the date value and the query result (`GenService.GetAll<StockPosition>()`), whether the date value and the service result are correct in the production and development?

Comment: @ZhiLv I have checked the date range, Dav and production are showing different dates but I am using Same PC.
Dev Mode
minExpDate: 30-09-2022 12:00:00 AM, MaxExpDate: 01-10-2022 12:00:00 AM
Production Mode
minExpDate: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, MaxExpDate: 1/2/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: As we can see that the issue relates the `aDetail.ExpiryDate`, you could check your code where you set its value. Besides, to prevent the time zone issue, you could consider setting the date time using UTC format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Problem was minExpDate and maxExpDate changes when run from production.So when I define the culture in the webconfig file then code work fine.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```